# Existence of closed geodesics in negatively curved locally symmetric spaces

Tags: riemannian-geometry, curvature

A *closed geodesic* in a Riemannian manifold is a geodesic which intersects itself in some point.

My question is

> Does every negatively curved, locally symmetric space of finite volume have a closed geodesic?

This statement is said to be a well-known fact in an article I read, however, I have not been able to find a reference in standard books such as Helgasons book on symmetric spaces or Wolfs book on  spaces of constant curvature.

Is it true? Why?

Comment: What about an ideal triangle in the hyperbolic plane?

Comment: What about a (trucated) cusps?

Comment: If you assume completeness then it is true for hyperbolic manifold, and may be you can use the same technique for every negatively curved manifold as well.

Comment: You do not even need locally symmetric (but you do need completeness). Most likely, this is proven in Gromov-Ballmann-Schroeder's book on manifolds of nonpositive curvature. There are several possible proofs, depending on your background, e.g. you can use ergodicity of the geodesic flow, or Borel density theorem, or just your bare hands.